# New line in Buefy tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I want to display a text that should contain a couple of new lines as the tooltip text.

```
<b-tooltip label="Item 1 \r\n Item 2 \r\n Item 3" size="is-small" type="is-light" position="is-top" animated multilined>
  <b-button type="is-primary" size="is-large" icon-left="compact-disc">
      Action
  </b-button>
</b-tooltip>
```

New lines using `\r\n` or `<br>` are not working.

How can I force a new line on that element?

It would be best to have a proper html content as the tooltip, but currently Buefy has no support for it.

Edit:

[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

Change the css white-space to `pre` or `pre-wrap`:

```
.b-tooltip:after {
  white-space: pre !important;
}
```

And use `&#xa;` instead of `\n`

```
  <b-tooltip label="Item 1 &#xa; Item 2 &#xa; Item 3" size="is-small" type="is-light" position="is-bottom" animated multilined>
    <b-button type="is-primary" size="is-large" icon-left="compact-disc">
      Action
    </b-button>
  </b-tooltip>
```

See: https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/xxwggad

Comment: Thanks. It works on the Codepen example, but it's not working on my website. I attached a screenshot. That's very strange, I can see via the dev tools that the white-space attribute is getting applied normally.

Comment: Is `white-space` applied to `:after` pseudo-element? and What text are you getting on data-label?

Comment: Yes, same as the codepen.  just the new line char that is not getting converted to a new line, which is odd. I tried typing the whole &#xa; and &#10; without success. It is treated as a simple text.

Comment: Right now, I'm using the same code as your example, the text is "Item 1 &#xa; Item 2 &#xa; Item 3", but later on I would like to get show some Text + numbers.